# Trailing cumulative values using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to perform a specific calculation across columns:  pwr - base + final to create a 'used' column. However, this has to be grouped by the id and date. Once the first calculation is established, the second calculation will be a cumulative of the newly created used column. Which will be: used column + final for each date row.

**Data**

```
pwr pos id  date    base    position    final   
100 40  aa  q121    50     20           15  
100 40  aa  q221    50     20           25  
100 40  aa  q321    50     20           10  
100 40  aa  q421    50     20           5   
50  30  bb  q121    25     10           0   
50  30  bb  q221    25     10           10
```

**Desired**

```
pwr pos id  date    base    position    final   used
100 40  aa  q121    50      20          15      65
100 40  aa  q221    50      20          25      90
100 40  aa  q321    50      20          10      100
100 40  aa  q421    50      20          5       105
50  30  bb  q121    25      10          0       25
50  30  bb  q221    25      10          10      35
```

**Doing**

```
df['used'] =  df['pwr'].sub(df.groupby('id')['date'].cumsum()).sub(df.groupby('id')['base'].cumsum()).add(df.groupby('id')['final'].cumsum())
```

However, the final column isnt calculating correctly. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to first find the first item , make all `repeated` value to NaN , then go to `groupby` with `cumsum`

```
s = df['pwr'].sub(df['base']).mask(df['id'].duplicated()).add(df['final'],fill_value=0)

df['new'] = s.groupby(df['id']).cumsum()
df
   pwr  pos  id  date  base  position  final    new
0  100   40  aa  q121    50        20     15   65.0
1  100   40  aa  q221    50        20     25   90.0
2  100   40  aa  q321    50        20     10  100.0
3  100   40  aa  q421    50        20      5  105.0
4   50   30  bb  q121    25        10      0   25.0
5   50   30  bb  q221    25        10     10   35.0
```

Comment: what if my pwr column is labeled as 'state pwr' How would I incorporate this? I did:
df.['state pwr'].sub....  but says invalid

Comment: @Lynn check the update

Comment: Hi I have seen that you are very knowledgeable about pandas and data science. I couldn't find way to contact you privately. I am trying to make as many connections as I possibly can and learn from coders as I go along. If it is cool to personally message you about some questions please do let me know

Comment: @georgehere perhaps tag him?